# How to print raw string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, escaping

I want to print *escaped* or *raw* version of a string.
For example: given this string:

```
"a,
b,
c,
d"
```

I want to get

```
"a,\nb,\nc,\nd".
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is not clear, in part because it's only newlines that you escape in your example. Please define what you mean by "escaped or raw version of a string". Aside: when you give an example (which is generally most helpful), please assign a variable to each of your input objects (e.g., `str = "a,...."`). That way, readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 8):

```
s = "a,
b,
c,
d"
s.dump
# => "\"a,\\nb,\\nc,\\nd\"" 
s.dump[1...-1]
# => "a,\\nb,\\nc,\\nd"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
string = 'a,
b,
c,
d'

> p string.inspect
#=> "\"a,\\nb,\\nc,\\nd\""
# "*** expected output ***"
> p string.inspect.delete('\"')
#=> "a,\\nb,\\nc,\\nd"
```

**[Demo](https://repl.it/B6mu/1)**

Comment: I think it's better to slice rather than `delete` if the string may contain `"`