# How can I print a string contained in an object as literal with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string-literals, line-endings

I'm trying to write a program which will detect if a file has `\n` or `\r\n` line endings and then fix them. I'm hoping to have the script output some messages to a console, but I'm running into trouble. I can't figure out how to print the line endings as literals.

Here is my method which checks for the line ending type:

```
def determine_line_ending(filename)
  File.open(filename, 'r') do |file|
    return file.readline[/\r?\n$/]
  end
end
ending = determine_line_ending(ARGV.first)
```

Supposedly this method will return either `\n` or `\r\n` if it matches one of those patterns on the first line of the file.

I would like to then print to the console which ending type was detected but if I use `puts ending` then it just adds a line ending to the console. I know that if I used `puts '\r\n'` then it will print them literal, or if I use double quotes I just have to escape the backslashes. But I'm pretty new to Ruby and I'm having a hard time just finding a way to print my variable as a literal instead of a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print raw string in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148616/how-to-print-raw-string-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you well, you want to print the "\r" string if the line ending is \r and "\r\n" if \r\n.

In this case you can use the *dump* function is what you need:

```
puts ending.dump // => "\r" or "\r\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use method `String#inspect`:

```
s = "abc\n\rdef"
puts s
puts s.inspect
```

This is very handy method that is defined on all objects. You can print hashes, arrays, whatever.